# basic currency converter, why doesn't it compile?

Tags: c#, console-application

Really new to programming so I hope this question isn't too annoying but I have hit a wall. I have to make a currency converter in c#, where there is 5 currencies with a stated value each. The console should ask thee user how much they want to convert, what they want to convert to and then display something like "you entered 25 EUR which converts to 27 USD

```
        double amount;
        double USD = 1.39;
        double GBP = .82;
        /*double CHF = 1.22;
        double AUD = 1.48;
        double CAD = 1.51;*/
        string currency;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of Euro you wish to be converted:");
        amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose the currency you wish to convert to:");
        Console.WriteLine("USD");
        Console.WriteLine("GBP");
        Console.WriteLine("CHF");
        Console.WriteLine("AUD");
        Console.WriteLine("CAD"); 
        Console.WriteLine("");
        currency = Console.ReadLine();

        switch (currency)
        {
            case "USD":
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount,      amount * currency, currency);
                break;
            case "GBP":

            default:
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid currency");
                break;
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```

"Operator * cannot be applied to operators of type double and string" is the error message Im receiving.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: You look like you are on the right track so far. Keep going until you are completely stuck and have a question for us.

Comment: Should we check if the code compiles?  Should we do your homework?  What is the question?

Comment: Why you're asking a user to choose currency, but expecting that he would enter coefficient to euro currency?

Comment: As others have indicated, you should be sure to state clearly what your question is! Also, if you are receiving an error message, be sure to post the message.

Comment: Move your hardcoded conversion factors into the math. "Currency" is no longer a number. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I was reading this in bed on my windows phone and it was bugging me.  So now I am up late at night typing this!

The problem is you are reading in currency as a string which will contain USD, GBP:

```
currency = Console.ReadLine();
```

And reading amount in as a string and converting to a double - for example 300.0:

```
amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

You are then using both variables in a multiplication to get the converted amount:

```
Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount,      amount * currency, currency);
```

With amount * currency.

You have 2 types which cannot be multiplied together.  String and Double!  Thus you get a design-time error.  Which you will see in the Visual Studio errors window:

```
Error   1   Operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'string'
```

You basically want to take the entered currency which is "USD", "GBP" and get the appropriate conversion factor from the variable you have named USD or GBP.

So in order to make your code "work" you need to do something like as follows:

```
switch (currency)
{
    case "USD":
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount,      amount * USD, currency);  // <-- here is the change
            break;
    ...
}
```

In the switch... case you know what the currency value is.  The above is case "USD" so you need to reference the USD variable.

To make your code better, get rid of that switch.  I would prefer a Dictionary where you could essentially store your strings (GBP, USD, etc) and have an associated conversion factor with each.  But you would be getting introduced to the world of generics, but just get a grasp of some of the basics would be your best introduction to programming.  But here you go!

```
        double amount;
        /* Dont need to declare these explicitly!            
        double USD = 1.39;
        double GBP = .82;
        double CHF = 1.22;
        double AUD = 1.48;
        double CAD = 1.51;*/
        string currency;
        Dictionary<string, double> factors = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        factors.Add("GBP", 0.82D);
        factors.Add("USD", 1.39D);
        // ... add other factors

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the amount of Euro you wish to be converted:");
        amount = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Please choose the currency you wish to convert to:");
        Console.WriteLine("USD");
        Console.WriteLine("GBP");
        Console.WriteLine("CHF");
        Console.WriteLine("AUD");
        Console.WriteLine("CAD");
        Console.WriteLine("");
        currency = Console.ReadLine();

        double factor;
        if (factors.TryGetValue(currency, out factor))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount, amount * factor, currency);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a recognised currency {1}", currency);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

As it is, this code will try to compare the value of currency to the exchange rate.  While that is possibly an interesting idea, I don't think it is what you want.  For starters, `currency` is likely supposed to be a `string`, so I will go with that assumption.  Your comparisons should be against `strings`, not doubles, but what you typed compares `currency` to the doubles you defined earlier to denote the exchange rate.  What you likely want is:

```
if (currency == "USD")
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount, amount * currency, currency);
```

and so on.  However, in this case your code will look much nicer with a switch statement, as such:

```
switch(currency)
{
    case "USD":
        Console.WriteLine("You have entered {0} EUR which converts to {1} {2}", amount, amount * currency, currency);
        break;
    case "GBP":
    ...
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid currency");
        break;
}
```

EDIT 1:

To explain why this doesn't compile, the problem is that you have the statement

```
currency == USD
```

This statement means compare the variable `currency` to the variable `USD`.  `USD` is a double and `currency` is a `string`.  The compiler does not know how to compare a `double` and a `string` (at least using a `==` operator).  Putting double quotes around a constant, like `"USD"`, tells the compiler to instead make a temporary `string` which has the value of that constant.  Of course, the `==` operator works between `strings`, so while

```
double USD = 1;
String currency = "1";
bool result = currency == USD;
bool result2 = currency == 1;
```

Generates two compiler errors,

```
String USD = "1";
String currency = "1";
bool result = currency == USD;
bool result2 = currency == "1";
```

Will be true for both statements.

Comment: the switch statement does make it look much better, trying to implement it now but the amount * currency has a blue underline and the error message appearing is operator type * cannot be applied to double and string

Comment: You still aren't putting quotes around `"USD"` and the other currencies.

Answer (score 1):

The currency variable should be a string and the comparison should look like `if (currency == "USD")`

Comment: How does this answer the question? We don't even know what the question is!

Comment: currency variable is of type double

Comment: thanks for replying, I did try putting the currency variable as a string, and it still wont compile? I cant figure out where to go from here is basically the question

Comment: @user3601058, so the question is: "Why doesn't this compile"?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET yes it is,  sorry for being vague Im still trying to get my bearings!

Comment: @user3601058, I edited your question to include this information. In case you aren't aware of it, you can do this yourself in the future by clicking the "edit" button beneath your post.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET thanks, I didn't know that could be done!

Answer (score 0):

Use following piece of code.

```
public string CurrencyConversion(decimal amount, string fromCurrency, string toCurrency)
{
    string Output = "";
    const string fromCurrency1 = "USD";
    const string toCurrency1 = "INR";
    const double amount1 = 2000;

    // Construct URL to query the Yahoo! Finance API
    const string urlPattern = "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}{1}=X&f=l1";
    string url = string.Format(urlPattern, fromCurrency1, toCurrency1);

    // Get response as string
    string response = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);

    // Convert string to number
    double exchangeRate =
        double.Parse(response, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    // Output the result
    Output=(amount1*exchangeRate).ToString();

    return Output;
// Ref: http://salmankavish.blogspot.in/2016/02/currency-converter-using-c.html
}
```