# C# Currency Converter: Reduce the amount of if statements

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement

So far I have created a Currency Converter that will convert between multiple different currencies however, to convert the currency, I have used 4 if statements per currency (so I can convert between all of the different currencies.) This has resulted in 20 if statements which doesn't seem very clean or efficient. Here is an example of my code:

```
if (currencyFrom == "B" && currencyTo == "U")
{
    currencyConversion = doubleInput * 1.29;
    Console.WriteLine("$" + currencyConversion);
}
if (currencyFrom == "B" && currencyTo == "E")
{
    currencyConversion = doubleInput * 1.14;
    Console.WriteLine("€" + currencyConversion);
}
if (currencyFrom == "B" && currencyTo == "J")
{
    currencyConversion = doubleInput * 145.10;
    Console.WriteLine("¥‎" + currencyConversion);
}
if (currencyFrom == "B" && currencyTo == "C")
{
    currencyConversion = doubleInput * 1.68;
    Console.WriteLine("$‎" + currencyConversion);
}
```

Is there a better way to do the same calculations but without as many if statements?

Thanks for your help,

Josh

Comment: You could put the conversion factors in a `Dictionary<ValueTuple<string, string>, decimal>` and look up the pairings there.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23554005/3060520

Comment: At the very least, change to use "else if". At the moment you're doing every comparison, even though only one can ever match.

Comment: For data that constantly changes, it's not a good idea to store it in the code. You really would want to have the currencies and multipliers all stored in a database table or some other external file, where it can potentially be maintained by a non-programmer. A maintenance programmer would not appreciate having to constantly make tedious little changes to this function.

Comment: Ultimately any solution which requires the application to be recompiled each time a currency conversion changes is going to be a problem to maintain over time. Eventually it will be canned because the person who wrote it will leave, and those left will forget how it's supposed to be built and deployed etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to reduce the amount of `if-statements` and your requirements do allow the use of internet-resources I have a very short code-sample that uses the ***Yahoo Finance***

```
public decimal ConvertCurrency(string from, string to)
{
    var uriString = string.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}{1}=X&f=l1", from, to);
    string response = new WebClient().DownloadString(uriString);
    return decimal.Parse(response, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Or the `async` way:

```
public async Task<decimal> ConvertCurrencyAsync(string from, string to)
{
    var uriString = string.Format("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s={0}{1}=X&f=l1", from, to);
    string response = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync(uriString);
    return decimal.Parse(response, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

With that code you have the benefit to convert from and to any currency and you do have the current exchange rate.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say the application is for a school assignment, so using an online service may not be an option. For a real-world project though, your solution would definitely be a better way to go.

Comment: Depending on the application usage, going for the online source might not be optimal in all scenarios. So caching the ratios in the (concurrent) dictionary and refreshing them on a given interval would be the best solution for performance. If the application would require precise ratios for each transaction then going for verified online resource would be better.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have implemented your method and it works perfectly. Just before I saw your answer, I was using Dictionary from the answer below which worked fine but your method ensures exchange rates are always up to date and uses even less code!

Comment: Please consider the comment of @JanneMatikainen as additional improvement of my code.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dictionary`

```
decimal currencyConversion;
        string currencyFrom = "B";
        string currencyTo = "E";
        decimal doubleInput = 1000m;

    Dictionary<string, decimal> dic = new Dictionary<string, decimal>();
    dic.Add("BU", 1.29m);
    dic.Add("BE", 1.14m);
    dic.Add("BJ", 145.10m);
    dic.Add("BC", 1.68m);

    currencyConversion = doubleInput * dic[currencyFrom + currencyTo];
```

Comment: Dictionary lookup will throw exception if there is no such key present in the dictionary however.

Comment: Of course, but this is only a way to help him reduce the amount of if statements.

Comment: @TienNguyen Not the only way. Without changing to use higher level data-structures, the obvious way to fix the if's, is to change them to be a switch.

Comment: @user1751825 That does indeed decrease the amount of `if`s but the branching complexity is all the same. It's not helpful at all, not to mention `switch` statements are harder to maintain (e.g. if more complex conditions are required).
@JanneMatikainen The exception may be intended as there is no proper way for the application to behave, or the fallback behavior should be implemented by the OP. It would however improve the answer to note this.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a dictionary to store the conversion ratios and then have much more cleaner function to do the calculation.

First declare a ConcurrentDictionary (so you could even update the ratios on the fly thread safely).

```
private readonly static ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, double> ConversionRatios = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<string, string>, double>();
```

You need to populate the ConversionRatios with your from and to currency pairs and their respective ratios.

```
static MyClass()
{
    ConversionRatios.TryAdd(new Tuple<string, string>("B", "U"), 1.29);
    ConversionRatios.TryAdd(new Tuple<string, string>("B", "E"), 1.14);
    ConversionRatios.TryAdd(new Tuple<string, string>("B", "J"), 145.10);
    ConversionRatios.TryAdd(new Tuple<string, string>("B", "C"), 1.68);
}
```

Then you can have a very simple convert function.

```
private static double Convert(double doubleInput, string currencyFrom, string currencyTo)
{
    double ratio;
    if (ConversionRatios.TryGetValue(new Tuple<string, string>(currencyFrom, currencyTo), out ratio))
    {
        return doubleInput * ratio;
    }

    // Handle case when no ratio is found, either throw exception or do what ever.
    throw new Exception("No ratio found.");
}
```

Comment: Why use `ConcurrentDictionary` when there are no threading requirements from the OP? It only increases the implementation/answer complexity without additional value.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
if (currencyFrom == "B") {
    switch (currencyTo) {
        case "U":
            currencyConversion = doubleInput * 1.29;
            break;
        case "E":
            ...
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch

As others have noted, using conditional logic like this does not make for a very scalable application. Switch is neater and simpler generally than using multiple if's, but there certainly would be more effective ways to re-design your application to make it scale better.

Comment: This will not scale well if more currencies are add later, so has the same inherent problems as the original in the question.

Comment: @ClickRick That's true. I was really just re-writing to use correct syntax, rather than refactoring to be more flexible and scalable. A better solution would presumably be to store all currencies and conversion multipliers in a database. Any other change is only a marginal improvement.

Comment: Learning the core syntax features of the language (like switch) is fairly important. I would suggest perhaps even more important initially than learning how to use more advanced data structures. From the posters code, it appears he is only just starting to learn C#.